# Parse XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I have a XML column in SQL Server.  Example data below

```
<row id="AC.1.TR.AUD.12800............" xml:space="preserve">
  <c1>AC</c1>
  <c2>1</c2>
  <c3>TR</c3>
  <c4>AUD</c4>
  <c5>12800</c5>
  <c17>20150129</c17>
  <c18>CREDIT</c18>
  <c18 m="2">DEBIT</c18>
  <c19>4289540.22</c19>
  <c19 m="2">-17955</c19>
  <c20 m="2" />
  <c21 m="2" />
  <c22>52287350.51</c22>
  <c22 m="2">-218862.47</c22>
  <c23>-688471.2</c23>
  <c23 m="2" />
  <c24 m="2">2881.77</c24>
  <c32 />
</row>
```

Starting from column c18 to c24 all are associated.  If there are two sets in 18, then there will two group set.  However,none of tags inside the two sets are mandatory.  I need to parse these into a normal table structure.

Here is the proper output:

```
RECID                        C18         C19       C22           C23      C24
AC.1.TR.AUD.12800.........  CREDIT   428950.22  52287350.51   -688471.2               
AC.1.TR.AUD.12800.........  DEBIT    -17955.00   -218862.47              2881.77
```

Note: I have tried nodes and values options but none are helping me out in getting the related values between the tags.

Comment: Can you add some expected output?  That would help me understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the repose @brian . Expected output should be as follows, 
"
CREDIT   428950.22  52287350.51   -688471.2              
DEBIT      -17955.00    -218862.47                         2881.77
"

Comment: @BrianPressler sorry not able to give clear picture on the output as I was not able to paste picture or proper format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a PIVOT to get the row data into columns:

```
SELECT ID, C18,C19,C22,C23,C24
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        Loc.value('../@id', 'varchar(255)') ID,
        isnull(Loc.value('@m', 'varchar(100)'),'') m,
        Loc.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)') c,
        Loc.value('.', 'varchar(100)') cValue
    FROM @XML.nodes('/row/child::node()') as T(Loc)
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (
    Max(cValue)
    FOR c IN (C18,C19,C22,C23,C24)
    ) AS PivotTable
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: You're welcome.  :)  If this answer worked for you, you can mark it as the official "Answer".  It rewards the poster of the answer and informs others that you found the answer useful.